typing a Callable with *args and keyword-only args
I am trying to make a system that records the methods calls of a class. (I already encountered some issues for which I posted yesterday and they were solved).
The idea is the following:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

RetType = TypeVar("RetType")
Param = ParamSpec("Param")
CountType = TypeVar("CountType", bound="FunctionCount")


class FunctionCount:
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict


def count(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
) -> Callable[Concatenate[CountType, str, Param], RetType]:
    def wrapper(
        self: CountType,
        /,
        *args: Param.args,
        log_name: str | None = None,
        **kwargs: Param.kwargs,
    ) -> RetType:
        function_name = log_name or f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
        if function_name not in self.count_dict:
            self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
        self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class A(FunctionCount):
    @count
    def test(self, multiplier: float) -> float:
        return multiplier


count_dict = dict[str, int]()
A(count_dict).test(2.0)
A(count_dict).test(multiplier=2.0, log_name="testing")

print(count_dict)
assert count_dict == {"A.test": 1, "testing": 1}

The script is executed without any problem but mypy has problems
It signals me that wrapper does not have the correct type:
Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[CountType, VarArg(Any), DefaultNamedArg(str | None, 'log_name'), KwArg(Any)], RetType]", expected "Callable[[CountType, str, **Param], RetType]")

I guess this is because I wanted log_name to be a keyword-only argument so understanding the call A(count_dict).test(2.0, log_name="testing") is quite easier than if we had A(count_dict).test(2.0, "testing")
I tried to use Protocol for the typing but then I had other problems
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar

RetType_co = TypeVar("RetType_co", covariant=True)
Param = ParamSpec("Param")
CountType_contra = TypeVar(
    "CountType_contra", bound="FunctionCount", contravariant=True
)


class FunctionCount:
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict


class CountableCallable(Protocol[CountType_contra, Param, RetType_co]):
    def __call__(
        _self,  # noqa: N805
        self: CountType_contra,
        /,
        *args: Param.args,
        log_name: str | None = None,
        **kwargs: Param.kwargs,
    ) -> RetType_co: ...


def count(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType_contra, Param], RetType_co],
) -> CountableCallable[CountType_contra, Param, RetType_co]:
    def wrapper(
        self: CountType_contra,
        /,
        *args: Param.args,
        log_name: str | None = None,
        **kwargs: Param.kwargs,
    ) -> RetType_co:
        function_name = log_name or f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
        if function_name not in self.count_dict:
            self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
        self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class A(FunctionCount):
    @count
    def test(self, multiplier: float) -> float:
        return multiplier


count_dict = dict[str, int]()
A(count_dict).test(2.0)
A(count_dict).test(multiplier=2.0, log_name="testing")

print(count_dict)
assert count_dict == {"A.test": 1, "testing": 1}

In this case, the A(count_dict).test(2.0) lines raise the following error:
Argument 1 to "__call__" of "CountableCallable" has incompatible type "float"; expected "A"

Calling A(count_dict).test(multiplier=2.0, log_name="testing") raises this error:
Missing positional argument "self" in call to "__call__" of "CountableCallable"

The only calling working is A.test(A(count_dict), 2.0) which is not the way people call methods.
I also tried to use a decorator instead of a wrapper but I would get the same alerts
I tried to intervert the names of the self and __self__ arguments for CountableCallable.__call__ but it did not do anything
So I was wondering if there was a Protocol variation that would allow me to specify that CountableCallable is a class method (so maybe we wouldn't have confusion)
Or if there was a way to use typing.Callable while precising that log_name is a keyword-only argument

You can't insert any parameters between P.args and P.kwargs. Either choose a different design or forgo static type checking altogether.

@InSync so I can't make log_name keyword-only ?

@Paulo-99 typechecker will only understand adding positional arguments, yes.

@STerliakov so I can't write a type for my wrapper without mypy rejecting it ?

@Paulo-99 exactly - there is no way to add arguments between P.args and P.kwargs and have it accepted by type checkers (mypy may swallow some variations, because there many ParamSpec problems, but they work on that; pyright will reject anything like this right away and is correct)

OK thank you to you both I will look for a new design

Just because the original definition of A.test doesn't use the log_name argument doesn't mean you can't required it to accept one for use by the decorator you apply.
